# incremental cumsum between predefined upper limits

Tags: r

I have the next data

```
ID <-c (1:10)
value <- c (501:510)
df <- data.frame (ID, value)
```

and I have to group data between the next upper limits (layers)

```
> Layers <- c (2, 4, 7, 8, 10)
```

The result I need is a value's cumsum from ID > layer[-1] & ID <= layer:

```
Layers  sum of value
2       1003            
4       1007
7       1518
8       508
10      1019
```

for example: the layer rownumber r = 5 (10) is **1019**,  because `layer [r-1] = 8` and `layer [r] = 10`, then `sum (df[ID > 8 & ID <= 10,value]) = 509 + 510 = 1019`

regards

Comment: Edit your Question , so as to explain the logic of the output you desired. so that people here can help you

Comment: It's not really clear how you choose the elements to sum... and what is `a` for anyways?

Comment: the layers are the upper limit of a bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following test:

```
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(501:510)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
group<- c(2,4,7,8,10)
print("Layer     sum a+b")
for(id in group)
{
 print(paste(id,"  sum(",c[id-1,2],"+",c[id,2],")",c[id-1,2]+c[id,2],ser=""))
}
```

Comment: your solution does not match the 4th line.  Though, I change the text a bit, for better understanding

Comment: How did you get the values of 7  1518 and 8      508 ???

Comment: 1518 = b(5) + b(6) + b(7), because I am summing up from bound's id 4 to 7

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make any sense; where is the logic you follow for each sum??

Comment: the column "a" is as a key-ID column, that indicates the bounds of the sum of b (from:to)